# As of Ember version 2.3.0, is there a difference between component "attributes" vs. component "properties?"

Tags: ember.js

In all ember documentation to date, they refer to a component's "properties."  For example, calls to `this.get('some_property')` and `this.set('some_property', 'some_value')` are referred to as getting/setting a component's *properties*.

As of the latest documentation in version 2.2.0, 2.3.0, particularly in the documentation regarding component lifecycle hooks, they are now using the term `attributes`.  This does not seem to be documented in the API and seems to be a concept that overlaps with `properties`.

Is there an effective difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, the distinction is merely in terminology, but it's introduced in a way to prepare users to glimmer (angle bracket) components.

Properties are internal to the component, and attributes are what's passed in to the component via bindings. Say you have the following:

```
// application.hbs
{{my-component foo="foo"}}

// my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  bar: "bar"
});
```

In this example, `foo` is an attribute (passed into the component via binding), and `bar` is a property (defined internally). In classic components however, attribute lookups are proxied, meaning that when you do `this.get('foo')` inside the component, you will get the value `"foo"` of the attribute.

In glimmer components, which aren't available yet so this is future-speak, you will need to lookup attributes in the `attrs` hash, so you'd have to do something like `this.get('attrs.foo')` to get the value `"foo"`.

I hope I don't confuse you further!

Answer (score 0):

Attributes prepare us for the future of angle bracket components and read-only binding, but they can also improve your life today! Using attributes, your actions can have return values:

```
// application.hbs
{{my-component save=(action "someActionWhichReturns")}}

// my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    save(user) {
      // sendAction eats the return value
      this.sendAction('save', user);

      // I can get the return value this way
      var result = this.attrs.save(user);
    }
  }
});
```

You can read more about the 2.x transition on the blog:
http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html

Comment: You shouldn't use `attrs` in classic components, I explain in more details in [To `attrs` or not to `attrs`](http://locks.svbtle.com/to-attrs-or-not-to-attrs).